# Not able to disable checkbox if I use ng-model and ng-disable in Chrome V57

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-disabled

I am getting red toaster error in Chrome version 57. If I use both `ng-model` and `ng-disable`.

I have tab like below:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-value="true" ng-model="classification" ng-disabled="classification === true">
```

By default classification is false. When user check the checbox, classification become true and same time disabling the checkbox.

It was worked fine in Chrome Version less than 57. Now we are using Chrome V57. This issue not occurring in IE and Mozilla.

We are using Angular 1.3

Kindly share if anyone have any solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this ,ng-disable="classification"

Comment: @Dushyantha: Yes I tried this too... but same result

Answer (score 0):

I created an example. Please check.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-disabled="checked">Check<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way, it's ng-disabled not ng-disable. I hope this may help you out.

Comment: Sorry it was typo mistake. Thanks @Ananya. This is also not working as expected in my application. I am able to disable the checkbox but getting below error: Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$rootScope/inprog?p0=NaNigest

Comment: This is digest cycle problem. Either we can use: 

if(!$scope.$$phase) {
  //$digest or $apply
//write updates here
}


OR


$timeout(function() {
  // anything you want can go here and will safely be run on the next digest.
})

Comment: but I am not sure where to add this code in my big application... @Ananya Could you  please suggest how to fix this issue ?

Comment: $(timeout(function() {
// Update scope variables i.e. classification
});

Try this once

Comment: I tried like below but same results. Let me correct if I am wrong. $scope.clickHere = function () {
    $(timeout(function() { 
     $scope.classification = true;
    }));
   }

Comment: $scope.clickHere = function () {
       $(timeout(function() { 
         $scope.$apply(function() {
           $scope.classification = true;  
         }); 
       }); 
     }